# Como fazer upload de uma imagem em NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, file-upload, stream

Boa tarde,

Quero fazer um **POST Request** do cliente em JAVASCRIPT com **DATA Send** (ficheiro .jpg) em data URL para o servidor em NODEJS.

[Cliente] - JavaScript

```
    finalImg.onload = function(event){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onload = function (event) {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        };

        request.open('post', '/setimageprofile', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'image/JPEG;charset=UTF-8');
        request.send(finalImg);
    }
```

[Server] - NodeJs

```
app.post('/setimageprofile', function(req, res) {
    //var request_data = '';
    var writable = fs.createWriteStream('./client_imgs/getusername.jpg');
    req.on('data', function(data){
        writable.write(data);
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        writable.end();
    });
});
```

[Problema]
Quando abro o ficheiro *./client_imgs/getusername.jpg* com o visualizador de imagens tenho o erro **"Não suportamos este formato de ficheiro"**.
Aparentemente deverei fazer um cast da data que me está a ser enviada, estarei certo? Se sim, como fazer?

[Nota]
No servidor tenho,

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Você pode colocar a solução que você encontrou em uma resposta mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE] Encontrei solução**

**[server]**

```
app.post('/setimageprofile', function(req, res) {
    var request_data = '';
    var writable = fs.createWriteStream('./client_imgs/getusername.png', 'base64');
    req.on('data', function(data){
        request_data += data;
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        request_data = JSON.parse(request_data).data;
        var base64Data = request_data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
        console.log(base64Data);
        writable.write(base64Data);

        writable.end();
    });
});
```

**[cliente]**

```
var data = { data : finalImgURL};
        console.log('type: ' + dataTypeFromParent);
        // post - send image to server
        finalImg.onload = function(event){
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onload = function (event) {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                }
            };

            request.open('post', '/setimageprofile', true);
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'plain/text;charset=UTF-8');
            request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
```